# Determine time complexity based on number of steps

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

There are four different algorithms in a class file which have a certain time complexity. The output below is the amount of steps it took for each sort given an array size n of random data. Could I get some help about how I would go about determining the time complexities? If one of the sorts had the time complexity of n^2, I'm pretty sure I would have to take the number of steps and divide by n^2 and see which number it approaches, but I'm not sure what to do after that. Hopefully my question is not too broad.

Thanks!

```
The array size is 100
Number of steps for Sort 1:         2543 
Number of steps for Sort 2:          813 
Number of steps for Sort 3:       495100 
Number of steps for Sort 4:          776 
The array size is 200
Number of steps for Sort 1:        10381 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         1870 
Number of steps for Sort 3:      3980200 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         1764 
The array size is 300
Number of steps for Sort 1:        20755 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         2999 
Number of steps for Sort 3:     13455300 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         2826 
The array size is 400
Number of steps for Sort 1:        40298 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         4244 
Number of steps for Sort 3:     31920400 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         3933 
The array size is 500
Number of steps for Sort 1:        65165 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         5448 
Number of steps for Sort 3:     62375500 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         5028 
The array size is 600
Number of steps for Sort 1:        90241 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         6697 
Number of steps for Sort 3:    107820600 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         6178 
The array size is 700
Number of steps for Sort 1:       122291 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         8030 
Number of steps for Sort 3:    171255700 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         7416 
The array size is 800
Number of steps for Sort 1:       157374 
Number of steps for Sort 2:         9053 
Number of steps for Sort 3:    255680800 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         8627 
The array size is 900
Number of steps for Sort 1:       202401 
Number of steps for Sort 2:        10674 
Number of steps for Sort 3:    364095900 
Number of steps for Sort 4:         9842 
The array size is 1000
Number of steps for Sort 1:       243032 
Number of steps for Sort 2:        12047 
Number of steps for Sort 3:    499501000 
Number of steps for Sort 4:        11101 
>
```

Comment: im asuming they are all sorting the same array correct? just sorting using different sorting techniques?

Comment: Why not plot the steps on a graph and compare their graphs to the graphs of different time complexities?

Comment: They are sorting the same array, correct. Just different techniques

Answer (score 3):

Standard trick for this is to plot the values on a log-log graph.

if you have a relation `y=A n^k` then `log(y) = log(A) + k log(n)` and you can see that the order is just the slope of the line.

For example here's the plot of `log(n) log(v)` for your first set of data:

[image]

which suggests a value of `k=2` - so your data is probably `O(n^2)`.

The image was generated using octave and

```
> n= [ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 ]
> v = [2543, 10381, 20755, 40298, 65165, 90241, 122291, 157374, 202401, 243032]
> plot(log(n), log(v))
```

Better estimates can be made using a proper linear fit.

The higher accuracy estimate of the order can be obtained using

```
> polyfit(log(n), log(v), 1)
ans =
    1.9892  -1.3227
```

Which shows the curve is approximately `v = 0.27 n^2` since `exp(-1.3)` is approcimately `0.27`.

It's worth noting that this will only get you the `p` term in `O(n^p log^q n)` type behaviour, and the curve will bend at the top in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do to simplify the problem.

1. Only consider sizes that are a power of 2 times the smallest size. In this example, the smallest size is 100, so the only sizes worth considering are 100, 200, 400, and 800.
2. Normalize all of the times relative to the time of the smallest sample. For example, the time for *sort 1 size 100* is 2543, so divide all of the times for sort 1 by 2543.

When you do that, the table reduces to

```
     s1   s2   s3   s4
100   1   1.0   1   1.0
200   4   2.3   8   2.3
400  16   5.2  64   5.1
800  62  11.1 516  11.1
```

From this table it's easy to see that when you double the size, the time taken by sort1 increases by a factor of 4, and the time taken by sort3 increases by a factor of 8. Also, it's immediately obvious that sort2 and sort4 have the same time complexity. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.